# Change texture on key down

Tags: c#, xna, xna-4.0, keyboard-events

Here it is my method to get keyboard state and change texture based on which key is pressed.

```cs
private void CheckKeyboardAndUpdateMovement()
{
    KeyboardState keyboardState = Keyboard.GetState();
    if (keyboardState.IsKeyUp(Keys.Left)) { ChangeTexture(1); }
    if (keyboardState.IsKeyUp(Keys.Right)) { ChangeTexture(2); }
    if (keyboardState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Left))
    {
        Movement -= Vector2.UnitX;
        ChangeTexture(3);
    }
    if (keyboardState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Right))
    {
        Movement += Vector2.UnitX;
        ChangeTexture(4);
    }
    if ((keyboardState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Space) || keyboardState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Up)) && IsOnFirmGround())
    {
        Movement = -Vector2.UnitY * JumpHeight;
    }
}
```

It works if direction are pressed, but doesn't make its own job when nothing is pressed (just because both the `IsKeyUp` are true). Only the cases' order prevents the static texture to be shown while moving the sprite...
My question is, how can I make a clean solution of this problem? I already have an idea, but I don't like it at all...

Comment: What are those 4 textures? And, more important, what should your game do when nothing is pressed? I can't understand.

Comment: They are the texture for (1) "sprite  stand still to the left", (2) "sprite  stand still to the right", (3) "sprite walking to the left", (4) "sprite walking to the right". When nothing is pressed, it must stand still, but facing the last direction.

Comment: Yap, definitely better, and your solution is not that bad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want another solution, but is still similar to yours.

```
enum Direction { Left = 1, Right = 2}
Direction dir = Direction.Left; //or whatever

private void CheckKeyboardAndUpdateMovement()
{
    KeyboardState keyboardState = Keyboard.GetState();

    ChangeTexture((int)dir);
    if (keyboardState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Left))
    {
        Movement -= Vector2.UnitX;
        ChangeTexture(3);
        dir = Direction.Left;
    }
    if (keyboardState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Right))
    {
        Movement += Vector2.UnitX;
        ChangeTexture(4);
        dir = Direction.Right;
    }
    if ((keyboardState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Space) || keyboardState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Up)) && IsOnFirmGround())
    {
        Movement = -Vector2.UnitY * JumpHeight;
    }
}
```

You can do something similar with walking sprites.

Answer (score 0):

The worst solution I thought on, it's to store the sprite direction when the last key has been pressed and make a check on the next update, but it will become a mess more the keys and textures I'll have to control...

```cs
// Having a "bool leftDirectionOnLastMovement;" (worst name ever seen)
private void CheckKeyboardAndUpdateMovement()
{
    KeyboardState keyboardState = Keyboard.GetState();
    if (keyboardState.IsKeyUp(Keys.Left) && leftDirectionOnLastMovement)
        ChangeTexture(1);
    if (keyboardState.IsKeyUp(Keys.Right) && !leftDirectionOnLastMovement)
        ChangeTexture(2);
    if (keyboardState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Left))
    {
        Movement -= Vector2.UnitX;
        ChangeTexture(3);
        leftDirectionOnLastMovement = true;
    }
    }
    if (keyboardState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Right))
    {
        Movement += Vector2.UnitX;
        ChangeTexture(4);
        leftDirectionOnLastMovement = false;
    }
    }
    if ((keyboardState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Space) || keyboardState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Up)) && IsOnFirmGround())
    {
        Movement = -Vector2.UnitY * JumpHeight;
    }
}
```

I really hope someone will suggest me a better way to do this...